# Calculating throughput over 1 Gbps link

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We have $1 Gbps$ ($10^9$ bits per second) link.
We send $1KB$ ($10^3$ Bytes(1 byte = 8 bits)) packet every $3 msec$. Need to calculate throughput.

Answer: $1KB pkt$ every $3 msec$ -> $330kB/sec$ throughput over $1 Gbps$ link

I do not understand this answer. Should not we do the following:
$\frac{10^3 * 8 \  bits}{3 * 10^{-3} seconds} = 10^6 * 8 * 3 = 24 * 10^6 = 24 Mbps$ throughput.

How did we get $330kB/sec$ instead of $24 Mbps$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $\frac{10^3\cdot 8~\text{bits}}{\color{red}{3}\cdot 10^{-3}~\text{seconds}} = 10^6\cdot 8\cdot \color{red}{3}\cdot \frac{\text{bits}}{\text{seconds}}$

This should instead be $\frac{10^3\cdot 8~\text{bits}}{3\cdot 10^{-3}~\text{seconds}} = 10^6\cdot 8\cdot \frac{1}{\color{red}{3}}\cdot\frac{\text{bits}}{\text{seconds}}$

If you were to do this instead, you should get approximately $2.667 ~\text{megabits per second}$, which is the same as approximately $333.3 ~\text{kilobytes per second}$ or $0.3333~\text{megabytes per second}$

If the problem asks you to express throughput in a specific format (megabits per second, megabytes per second, gigabytes per second, bits per second, etc...) then try to match that format.  Otherwise, an answer of $2.667 ~\text{mbps}$ is just as good as an answer of $333.3~\text{kBps}$ since they represent the same thing.